# Referencing $(this) while looping through a class

Tags: php, jquery, this, each

I have a number of tables on a page. The contents are generated by a php script given a keyword (kuid - loaded from a database) and loaded in with jQuery.

On the page they look something like this:

```
<table class="className" kuid="someInteger"></table>
```

Here is the jQuery I came up with:

```
jQuery('.className').each(function(){
  var kuid = jQuery(this).attr('kuid');
  jQuery.post('data.php',{kuid: kuid},function(data){
    jQuery(this).html(data);
  });
});
```

and the data.php:

```
$kuid = $_POST['kuid'];
echo 'Content for this ID: '.$kuid.'!';
```

However it throws an 'Uncaught TypeError'. Apperently I'm not allowed to use the `$(this)` keyword, but I don't understand why.

This code works somewhat:

```
var kuid = jQuery('.className').attr("kuid");
jQuery.post(data.php',{kuid: kuid},function(data){
  jQuery('.className').html(data);
});
```

but it gives every table the same contents based on the first occurence of "kuid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use jquery function $.proxy

```
jQuery('.className').each(function(){
  var kuid = jQuery(this).attr('kuid');
  jQuery.post('data.php',{kuid: kuid},$.proxy(function(data){
    jQuery(this).html(data);
  }, this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign `$(this)` to a variable before going inside `post`:

```
jQuery('.className').each(function(){
  var kuid = jQuery(this).attr('kuid'),
      that = jQuery(this);

  jQuery.post('data.php',{kuid: kuid},function(data){
    that.html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: You could explain why the original did not work too?

Comment: This has an unexpected side effect. Only the last table on the page is getting content - it flashes quickly through all the kuid's. The funny thing is that due to the POST request it is somewhat random which one ends up on top. Most of the time it is the last, but sometimes it's the second to last.